# Forward ports for 2 local applications

Tags: windows, networking, port-forwarding, port, localhost

I have 2 local applications which communicate over TCP/IP using hard-coded (fixed) port. This works ok when there is only 1 user on a workstation. However, the second user of the workstation can't use the applications because the port is occupied by the applications of the first user.

If it's possible, then how to set per-user policy to forward the port for just these 2 applications? Something like a rule "if application A binds to localhost port N then bind it to localhost port N+1" and "if application B connects to localhost port N then connect it to localhost port N+1".

Administrative or programmatic solution is ok. The OS is Windows Server 2012 R2.

Comment: Is it about port forwarding, like on a router? You used the phrases "bind it to localhost", "connects to localhost", so maybe it's purely local communication? I'm somewhat confused. If local: can you choose the IP the application binds to? E.g. A would bind to `127.0.0.1` on the fixed port; B would bind to `127.0.0.2` on the same port.

Comment: It's purely local communication. I can't choose the IP the application binds to. I believe it binds to `0.0.0.0`. I say "port forwarding" because it's an analogy that comes to my mind: like on a router/firewall, but local within a machine.

Comment: So you'd like to make the application "think" it binds to the hard-coded port, while in fact it binds to *another* port?

Comment: @KamilMaciorowski, yes, and I would like the corresponding for the connecting application too.

Comment: I understand you can't choose which port the connecting application connects to. Can you at least change the target IP? or is it hard-coded also?

Comment: Might be easier to look into something like VM's or Docker to provide seperate namespaces.